# How to automatically mark a specific field either False or true after certain time has been elapsed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, automation

I'm creating a Hotel table reservation web app in Django 3.x.x

I have a `Table` Model with `isBooked` field that is set to either `False` or `True` depending on a table status. Code for this model:

```python
class Table(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    t_id = models.IntegerField("Table ID", null=True, unique=True)
    isBooked = models.BooleanField('Is Booked', default=False)
    chairs_booked = models.IntegerField("Chairs Booked", default=0)
    max_chairs = models.IntegerField("Total Chairs", default=0)
    max_book = models.IntegerField("Least Bookable", default=0)
    chairs_left = models.IntegerField("empty chairs", default=0)
```

Now, I have another Model called `Reservation` that stores data for booked `Tables`. Here is its code:

```python
class Reservation(models.Model):
    t_username = models.CharField("Booked By", max_length=100, null=True)
    t_email = models.EmailField("Email Address", null=True)
    t_phone = models.IntegerField("Phone Number", default=0, null=True)
    t_id = models.IntegerField("Table Id", null=True)
    booked_date = models.CharField("Check In Date", null=True, max_length=50) # '2020-10-27'
    booked_time = models.CharField("Check in Time", null=True, max_length=50) # '7:00'

    def _get_checkout_date(self):
        t = self.booked_date
        return t

    checkout_date = property(_get_checkout_date)

    def _get_checkout_time(self):
        the_time = dt.datetime.strptime(self.booked_time, '%H:%M')
        new_time = the_time + dt.timedelta(hours=3)
        return new_time.strftime('%H:%M')

    checkout_time = property(_get_checkout_time)
```

at this point, I have a `table` with following information stored in variables:

1. `booked_time` this holds a string for time showing when table was booked e.g. `7:00`
2. `checkout_time` this holds a string for time showing when table should be vacated/checked-out e.g `10:00`

so based on the above variables, I want to automatically mark a table's `isBooked` property to `False` after certain time has passed (e.g. 3 hours) since it was booked. How do I pull off such a thing?

if this is bad design ( It smells like one..)  how do I automatically mark a table either `booked/Free` using this information/fields available in their respective models?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to update such data in database level, a solution would be using cronjobs, but this means to leave Django's domain.

It's not usual such a need, as often the meaning of the information is useful on application level, rather than database level. This means that you should evaluate how much time has passed, or if the passed time is above/below a threshold within a view function or model function.

An elegant solution for this would be to add a property to your model, and remove the is_booked field:

```py
@property
def is_booked(self):
  time_treshold_in_hours = 3
  booked_datetime = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(self.booked_date, self.booked_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
  booked_deltatime = datetime.now() - booked_datetime
  return booked_deltatime.seconds // 3600 > time_treshold_in_hours
```

and within the view you are evaluating if a table is booked, you can do:

```py
def book_table(request):
  # <get table>

  if table.is_booked:
    return HttpResponse('This table is booked already')

  # <do your booking>
```

I'd also recommend changing the fields booked_date and booked_time to:
`booked_on = models.DecimalField()`

Comment: hi, thanks for your time. so, I tried to check your function, I couldn't get the required results. but let's say I tweak this function to my needs and it starts working, where would I implement this or how would I ensure that this function runs every 3 hours or so? I can't remove field from the database because it's being used in my view to check if table is booked or not. depending on its value it shows either red or green Pic of the table. the same field is being used in booking form where I'm checking if table is not booked then it shows up in the form "choose table for booking"

Comment: Hi,
Removing is_booked field from your model and creating the `@property` function will not break your views. It's likely that you don't need to run anything periodically, you can verify if a table is booked (i.e. if a certain amount of time passed since booking) on demand
The presented `@property` should do this verification